# After Adding Aria Tag , Screen Reader not able to read

Tags: html, jquery, wai-aria, jaws-screen-reader

I have Added aria-label but still Screen Reader not able to read Warning for which is 1st div .
focus goes on 1st div but not reading anything. How to tell screen reader to read warining icon ?

```
<div aria-label="Warning for" class="col-xs-1 color-red-1 hbmi-warning m-t-2"></div>
<div class="col-xs-10 p-l-1x p-r-unset">Deductible Amount</div>
```

Comment: I suggest you start here: https://w3c.github.io/using-aria/#practical-support-aria-label-aria-labelledby-and-aria-describedby. It looks like you need give the div a suitable role.

Comment: I have tried using role also not working . role="alert"  , if i use other role then it reads the role name also . tested with role="img"   its read as Warning for graphics.

Answer (score 0):

`aria-label` is mainly to be used on interactive elements, although [the doc for `aria-label`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-label) doesn't specifically say that.

This doc talks about elements you can reliably use it on, https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#practical-support-aria-label-aria-labelledby-and-aria-describedby.  The third last bullet point says:

- *Don't use aria-label or aria-labelledby on a `span` or `div` unless its given a role.*

I would not randomly throw a `role` on the `<div>`, especially something like `alert`.

What behavior are you trying to achieve?
Is the `div` an error icon?
Do you want screen reader users to find this `div`?  It's not an interactive element.